# Scrapy bulk insert

Tags: mysql, scrapy

I have a crawler that fetches data from multiple websites and update the information into a mysql table. I am using scrapy for writing the crawler.The crawler would be inserting/updating a large number of columns. Is it possible to bulk insert/update the items in scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but you can set up a mysql pipeline in the pipelines.py of your scrapy project, something like this:

```
class SQL(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='user', passwd='pass', db='DB', host='servername', charset='utf8')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (month, year, date) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', (item['month'], item['year'], item['date']))
            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print item
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        return item
```

Then enable it in settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'PROJECTNAME.pipelines.SQL': 300}
```

Comment: If scrapy writes to sql one record a time, it would take up a lot of time compared to writing say 10,000 records in one bulk query. I wanted to understand if I can specify such a number (like 10,000) when scrapy will flush the records to MySQL